# Python/Django: No module named 'xx.xx' when attempting import to urls.py

Tags: python, django, module, directory

I'm working on a Django project, and this is my directory structure:

[image]
Now I'm working on main project's root `urls.py` file in the configuration directory `learningUsers`, and want to import views.py file from basic_app, but when i can't basic_app in main urls file and when trying to import like;from learningUsers.basic_app import views, its showing an error of No module named 'learningUsers.basic_app'

Comment: maybe it should be from basic_app import views?

Comment: from basic_app import views isn't working even it cant find basic_app because they both are a different directory

Comment: if you include this app in settings.INSTALLED_APPS, it should work as I wrote in comment

Comment: @ElginCahangirov its already there even i also tried 'learningUsers.basic_app' but cant find a way

Answer (score 0):

Try `import learningUsers.basic_app.views` instead. `from` suggests that you are importing from a module and it will assume that learningUsers.basic_app is a module, which it isn't

Comment: Can you send the error it sent this time? It should work fine

Comment: here is the eror code
  File "C:\Users\Wasif Balol\Desktop\course_projects\learningUsers\learningUsers\urls.py", line 19, in <module>
    import learningUsers.basic_app.views as view
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'learningUsers.basic_app



and here are my imports
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url, include
import learningUsers.basic_app.views as view

Comment: What script are you trying to run this from? I notice that there are 2 directories with the same name so Python might be getting slightly confused

Answer (score 0):

If you're editing `learningUsers/urls.py`, then you'd want something like:

```py
from django.urls import path

from basic_app.views import HomeView

urlpatterns = [
    path("", HomeView.as_view(), name="home"),
]
```

You could also do `from basic_app import views`, then change to `path("", views.HomeView.as_view(), name="home"),` in your `urlpatterns`.

Comment: my problem is i cant call basic_app in learningUsers/urls,py file

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your basic_app folder is in learning_users folder.

Comment: Is emphasis here on "use name with snake_case, not camelCase"? Because on provided screensot it looks like `basic_app` folder is already in `learningUsers`.